# Did James Bond only wear Omega watches?

Tags: props, james-bond, product-placement

I am in a rabbit hole of what James Bond's watch preference was.  I have read that Ian Fleming wanted James Bond to go with Rolex; however have seen Omega watches being worn by Pierce Brosnan and Daniel Craig in their films.  Any context to this would be great with regard to what James Bond's watch preference was.

Comment: Is it being too cynical to note that James Bond is likely to prefer whoever is paying him [i e. the movie studio] the most to wear it?

Comment: Do you realize *almost all* product placements in movies are bought and paid for?  Wasn't so 40 years ago, so Bond's choices of things like Rolex or Walther PPK or Lotus were Ian Fleming's artistic choice.  IBM and Pan Am didn't pay for placement in 2001:A Space Odyssey. Now, the brand goes to the high bidder.   In fact you often see episodic TV where it's *obviously* an iMac or Macbook, but half the time they'll put a gray circle over the Apple logo because the production is holding out for a placement deal.

Comment: And, ironically, the tape/digital blur/whatever hiding the brand logo is more than obvious enough in shape and placement to still be able to identify the brand being "hidden".

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Apple also has a policy that their products can't be used by the bad guys in a movie/TV show. I'm not sure how they define this for shows with anti-heroes like Breaking Bad or Dexter.

Comment: @Barmar: The "good guy" (Dexter) was shooting Nikon, while [pedophiles were shooting Canon](https://dexter.fandom.com/wiki/Nathan_Marten?file=Nathan_Marten_7.PNG). XD

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica: Product placements also used to be kinda subtle. They're now integrated into the [freakin' script](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oB5hzlDe10c).

Comment: @EricDuminil The ease of FF'ing through commercials on TV has resulted in lots of of that kind of PP there as well. I've seen quite a few shows where there was dialogue like "The GPS navigation in <car model> is really great."

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica yeah I just watched a Polish thriller (The Defense) where all cars other than Lexus had the badges removed and they mentioned multiple times how the Hybrid Lexus didn't have many emissions :)

Comment: I've seen a lot more US shows that blank or anonymise car badges than in the UK. Here it just doesn't seem to matter. It's rare you notice this as product placement, mainly it's just 'random cars in a street' plus the hero, who rarely drives anything spectacular, or if they do it's an old classic. Even the famously non-advertising BBC doesn't bother with this. [BTW, the early Bond watches were apparently Connery's personal property]

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The early films he wore Rolex, then went through a mixture of various types, analog & digital - Breitling, Gruen, several Seikos, TAG Heuer, until there was a deal signed with Omega for Goldeneye. It's been Omega ever since.

Ref: Manofmany - [A Complete List of All James Bond 007 Watches](https://manofmany.com/fashion/watches/a-complete-list-of-all-the-james-bond-watches). List is not quite complete but runs from Dr No to Spectre.
Watchtime - [James Bond’s Watches: The Complete Movie Timeline](https://www.watchtime.com/featured/watches-james-bond/) just about agrees, with some movies having more than one watch.